# Replacing JSON value in python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

**EDIT: sorry, i had a hard to see uppercase/lowercase typo. please someone delete this question.**

I am trying to change the value of a json object with simplejson.
The problem is that instead of replacing it, it is adding another entry with the same key.

```
{
  "main" : "value_to_replace"
}
```

and after doing this in python:

```
json["main"] = "replaced"
```

becomes

```
{
  "main" : "value_to_replace",
  "main" : "replaced"
}
```

which is infact still valid json.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using your code sample as provided.  While repeated keys _might_ be technically valid JSON, keys in python dictionaries are unique, so you can't create the second structure.

Comment: python2 or python3? Did you enter all of the above in the interpreter? Or did some come from files? Or... we need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works for me.

```
import simplejson as json

str = """{
  "main" : "value_to_replace"
}"""
data = json.loads(str)
print data
data["main"] = "test"
print data
```

Output:

```
(test)alexandr@alexandr:~/Desktop$ python test.py
{'main': 'value_to_replace'}
{'main': 'test'}
```

Comment: you are right, i had a stupid typo.